Mailto-Link for Several Recipients
In HTML it is possible to create an e-mail link for several recipients via mailto:first@recipient.com;second@recipient.com?cc=third@recipient.com?subject=E-Mail%20List. I would like to create such a link to send it to a coworker, however Apple Mail does not allow for such links. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Unfortunately Apple Mail doesn’t use HTML.  The bottom line is to get what you’re after you need a client that does have HTML support (Outlook, Thunderbird, etc.)
Also, consider leaving a feature request on Apple’s Feedback page:  https://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html. The more feedback they get, the better Apple can develop the products to  meet our needs
